# Jenkins cvs-plugin configuration

Tags: jenkins, cvs

I'm trying to migrate from jenkins 1.459 to 1.580.
And the CVS-plugin changes from 1.6 to 2.12

In the 1.6 cvs-plugin, we use the `.cvspass` file to store CVS passwords.
We have a lot of jobs and a lot of repositories and we do not want to store the password in each jobs.

But in 2.11, it seems that the plugin do not use this file anymore. *Am I correct?*
So all jobs need specify the password for the repository.

As our security policy change the password every two months, I do not want to change the configuration of every jobs.

Is it possible to configure CVS repositories at a jenkins configuration level and not as a per-job configuration level?

In `Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System`, I see that I can add as many CVS Root + a username + a password.

In the `job configuration`, I need to specify a CVS root that should contains a username and optionally a password.

How can I configure jobs to use configuration from the jenkins configuration?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In the Jenkins 'Configure System' page, you can enter the CVSRoot and a username and password to be used for that repository. On the job configuration page you can then just enter the CVSRoot exactly as it was in the 'Configure System' page and it will use that central username and password. If you need to configure a job to use a specific username then you can enter the CVSRoot with a username (e.g. :pserver:username@server:port:/path/to/repo) in the job configuration section, and an entry with the matching CVS Root and username from the 'Configure System' page will be used.

Do not tick the 'This repository requires a password' checkbox on the job configuration page, otherwise it wont perform a lookup against the centrally configured credentials, and therefore wont pick up any updates to the centrally managed credentials.